# Replace an Entire Row in Pandas with its Predecessor (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
x                         y   event
20150622.172807.769815   382
20150622.172807.769818   327
20150622.172807.769825   399  event
20150622.172807.769836   342
...
20150622.172807.769899   559
```

In the column "event", if there is an event, I want to replace the entire row with the value of the previous row, like this:

```
x                         y   event
20150622.172807.769815   382
20150622.172807.769818   327
20150622.172807.769818   327
20150622.172807.769836   342
...
20150622.172807.769899   559
```

My code is:

```
for i, element in enumerate(df['event']):
    if element == 'event':
        df.ix[i,'event']= df['event'][i-1]
    else:
        df.ix[i,'event']= df['event'][i]
```

However, it keeps telling me the following error:

```
KeyError: -1
```

What is wrong with the code?
Thank you all!!!

Comment: What if you have consecutive rows that have `event` in the column?

Comment: Have you considered the case in which the first row has an event? You'll try to replace it with the previous row, but the previous row doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sure that the event never occurs in the first row and if the event is consecutive, it is replaced by the predecesor (if there are 10 consecutive rows, the 10 will have the same values of the previous row). But also, the event never occurs consecutive times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way to change rows, that works perfectly when changing rows of some columns (not changing all columns, but some of them).

Consider the same dataframe:

```
df
#                        x      y   event
0  20150622.172807.769815  382.0   
1  20150622.172807.769818  327.0   
2  20150622.172807.769825  399.0   event
3  20150622.172807.769836  342.0   
4  20150622.172807.769899  559.0
```

Suppose that you only want to change "y" column with its predecesor. The result will be something like this:

```
df
#                        x      y   event
0  20150622.172807.769815  382.0   
1  20150622.172807.769818  327.0   
2  20150622.172807.769825  327.0   event
3  20150622.172807.769836  342.0   
4  20150622.172807.769899  559.0
```

So, the best solution that I found is:

```
df['y'] = df['y'].where(df['event']!='event',df['y'].shift())
```

"Where" function is very helpful for those cases. Although is similar to .loc, for me it is more friendly the sintaxis of .where.

Thank you all again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have consecutive rows that have `event` in the `event` column, and the index don't duplicate, you might do; Here use `shift` to move all rows by one towards the end, and modify the data frame when the event column contains `event`;

```
df.loc[df.event == 'event', ['x', 'y']] = df[['x', 'y']].shift()

df
#                        x      y   event
#0  20150622.172807.769815  382.0   
#1  20150622.172807.769818  327.0   
#2  20150622.172807.769818  327.0   event
#3  20150622.172807.769836  342.0   
#4  20150622.172807.769899  559.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get that error when I run your code.  However, it seems as though your code only replaces the string `event`, not the whole row.  The following code (based off of yours) worked for me (including consecutive events):

```
    #creating sample df    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[1,2,3,4,5],
                 'event': ['NaN','NaN','event','event','NaN']})

        for i, element in enumerate(df['event']):
            if element == 'event':
                df.ix[i]= df.ix[i-1]
```

this gives the following output:

```
  event  x  y
0   NaN  1  1
1   NaN  2  2
2   NaN  2  2
3   NaN  2  2
4   NaN  5  5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it just like you proposed it, but it tells me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module> KeyError: 3`

    ....